# Removing everything after a certain char (IndexOfAny and Remove)

Tags: c#, java, string, indexof

I have the following string array (quantityInForPriceBandPopUp[3]) data:

```
10 - 24
25 - 99
100 - 249 
5000+
```

In C#, if I put this array through this:

```
quantityInForPriceBandPopUp[i] = quantityInForPriceBandPopUp[i].Remove(quantityInForPriceBandPopUp[i].IndexOfAny(new char[] { ' ', '+' }));
```

I get this:

```
10
25
100
5000
```

How do I reach the same result in Java? Ideally I am looking for a one line answer. If it is impossible, then the shortest would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient, but you could use regular expressions and [replaceFirst](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  arr[i] = arr[i].replaceFirst("( |\\+).*$","");
}
```

Basically, it finds the first instance of either a space `' '` or plus sign `+`, which we had to escape with two `\` since `+` is also a special symbol in regular expressions, along with any other characters following it `.*` up to the end `$`, and replaces it with an empty string.

If you needed to extend the code to catch other delimiters, like maybe `.`, you just add the delimiter to the group with another `|` operator:

```
  arr[i] = arr[i].replaceFirst("( |\\+|\\.).*$","");
```

Now, this will compile a new regex [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) each loop, which is definitely not ideal if you have a lot of Strings in your array. In that case, you might consider compiling a separate pattern first outside your loop:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("( |\\+).*$");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  arr[i] = pattern.matcher(arr[i]).replaceFirst("");
}
```

---

If you want the parts afterwards, a regular expression like this would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  arr[i] = arr[i].replaceFirst("^.*( |\\+)\\s*","");
}
```

Note, this would need to be modified if you still want to capture "5000" for "5000+".

It may be worth your while to make a separate generic regex that uses "\d+" to locate numbers, like:

```
^(\\d+).*((\\d+)?)$
```

Then it's just a matter of using a Matcher and [Matcher.group](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to pick out specific numbers.

**Related links**:

[String documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

[Pattern documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

[Matcher documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

[Regular Expressions in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

[Wikipedia on Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Patterns and Matchers are usually powerful than String.indexOf(), but are quite expensive is four are doing simple character detection, where indexOf is much faster.

Comment: @David Oliván Ubieto I completely agree, as I noted that my solution wasn't particularly efficient, but as the question asked for a one-liner, replaceFirst met that requirement, plus its very easy to extend for other delimiters.

Comment: thank you, your options works best for me. Can you please also modify your example to select the last part of the string array (24, 99, 249)?

Comment: @Prostak I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the string is "(24, 99, 249)"? I'd be happy to revise my answer if need be :-)

Comment: @Prostak Oh, wait, now I understand you. You want the parts at the end. Ok, I can do that :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient one-line answer, because there is no direct equivalent to `indexOfAny` in the `java.lang.String` API.

Here's an efficient equivalent in a couple of lines.

```
int pos = Math.min(Math.max(s.indexOf(' '), -1), Math.max(s.indexOf('+'), -1));
if (pos != -1) {
    s = s.substring(0, pos);
}
```

And you could easily turn that into a static helper method.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

It has the indexOfAny method and many more string methods

Comment: Specifically, the IndexOfAny method.

Comment: I don't see how to use your link. In Eclipse when I import either java.lang.Object or org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils and use indexOfAny, I get the following error: 'The method indexOfAny() is undefined for the type String.'

Comment: @Prostak You might need to download the Apache Commons library separately. It isn't bundled as part of Java.